# Propel Many-To-Many hydration problems

Tags: php, mysql, propel

My problem is I can't seem to hydrate Propel ORM object in case of a Many-To-Many relationship and even if I select everything from every table with find() it will still send out query in case of a Many-To-Many relation.

I've found many questions about this here on stackoverflow and many other places, but none work for me. Here it is the same exact question with an accepted answer which also doesn't work for me:
[find query for many to many relation propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007982/find-query-for-many-to-many-relation-propel)

My problem is quite the same only with other schema.

My schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="propelDB" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore" namespace="TestDB">
  <table name="c_catalogs_locations" idMethod="native" phpName="CCatalogsLocations" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="catalogid" phpName="Catalogid" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="locationid" phpName="Locationid" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
      <foreign-key foreignTable="catalogs">
          <reference local="catalogid" foreign="id"/>
      </foreign-key>
      <foreign-key foreignTable="locations">
          <reference local="locationid" foreign="id"/>
      </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="catalogs" idMethod="native" phpName="Catalogs">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="userid" phpName="Userid" type="INTEGER"/>
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="images" phpName="Images" type="LONGVARCHAR"/>
      <foreign-key foreignTable="users">
          <reference local="userid" foreign="id"/>
      </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="locations" idMethod="native" phpName="Locations">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="location" phpName="Location" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
</database>
```

The query I'm trying:

```
$locations = \Base\LocationsQuery::create()
    ->join("Locations.CCatalogsLocations")
    ->join("CCatalogsLocations.Catalogs")
    ->with("Catalogs")
    ->find();

foreach($locations as $location)
{
    echo "- " . $location->getLocation() ."<br>";
    foreach($location->getCatalogss() as $catalog) {
        echo "-- " . $catalog . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

(I know class names aren't nice but it's only a test project so I didn't care about it.)

The link to the documentation I'm useing and searching: http://propelorm.org/documentation/
I use the newest propel cloned from git with composer.

I've been digging in propel's documentation but I haven't find it definitely written down that it cannot do this, but I also couldn't solve it with any join(), joinWith(), or with() methods.

I set propel to use "classname": "Propel\Runtime\Connection\DebugPDO" so it logs every query sent out, and any query I try show that my objects doesn't hydrated properly and propel fires a query every time I call $location->getCatalogss() on one side of the many-to-many connection.

Propel log:

```
[2014-10-17 09:25:50] propelDB.INFO: SELECT locations.id, locations.location, catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM locations INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (locations.id=c_catalogs_locations.locationid) INNER JOIN catalogs ON (c_catalogs_locations.catalogid=catalogs.id) [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=8 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=9 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=10 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=13 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=14 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=15 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=11 [] []
[2014-10-17 09:25:51] propelDB.INFO: SELECT catalogs.id, catalogs.userid, catalogs.name, catalogs.images FROM catalogs INNER JOIN c_catalogs_locations ON (catalogs.id=c_catalogs_locations.catalogid) WHERE c_catalogs_locations.locationid=12 [] []
```

I see that the SELECT query that propel fires first is the one I want to use, so it fetches all Location rows connected with it's catalogs rows, but it only hydrates the locations not the catalogs.
It would be fine to do this even with 2 query to separately hydrate Locations and Catalogs or even the crossRefTable and have Propel handle the join but even if I hydrate them, but propel still doesn't use it's local data but send out the separate query.

Am I doing something wrong? How did you solved it?
Any idea how to solve it with custom hydration so it requires maximum as many query as many tables there are (they wont be huge tables with big data so query a whole table not a problem and I need them anyway)