# Selecting from a table using different relationships

Tags: symfony1, propel

I have three tables (objects). The Foo table has a 1:N relationship defined with the table Bar. The table FooBar is used to define a different N:M relationship between A and B.

I want to select all objects in Foo which have either a 1:N relationship with Bar and/or a N:M relationship using the same Criteria. So far, what I have is two different Criteria for each:

```
  $c1n = new Criteria();  
  $c1n->addJoin(FooPeer::ID, BarPeer::FOO_ID);

  $cnm = new Criteria();  
  $cnm->addJoin(FooPeer::ID, FooBarPeer::FOO_ID); 

  $objects1N = FooPeer::doSelect($c1n);  
  $objectsNM = FooPeer::doSelect($cnm);
```

Is it possible to include both in the same criteria? And if it is, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I can't think of a better title. But the current one doesn't really please me. Please, tell me if you can think of a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly, but see if this works for what you are looking for:

[find query for many to many relation propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007982/find-query-for-many-to-many-relation-propel)

You should be able to easily hydrate the 1:N relationship.

```
foreach($query as $result) {
    $result->getBar()->getColumnName();
}
```